# Edge can't see .SCSS file (ie. Sass)

Tags: sass, microsoft-edge

I am running Sass off localhost during development. While Chrome is fine, Edge is reporting:

> The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform
>   Resource Identifier):
>
> (XHR)GET - http://localhost/website/css/style.scss

It doesn't prevent the CSS from rendering, but it's a console error I'd rather avoid.

For what it's worth, the last line in my generated CSS (style.css) is:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Comment: It seems strange to me that the browser try to load a .scss file, it should rather be a compiled .css. Also does style.css.map exists next to style.css?

Comment: Yes. The usual style.css, style.css.map and style.scss are all in the same folder.